# Maximize $u_x(0)$ for a harmonic function $u:D\rightarrow [0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $u$ is a harmonic function from $D$ to $[0,1]$, where $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is the open unit disk centered at $0$.  What is the maximum of $u_x(0)$?

My solution: first we assume that $U\supset\overline{D}$ is an open ball and $u:U\rightarrow[0,1]$ is harmonic on $U$, then there exists an analytic function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\text{Re }f=u$ on $U$. The [Schwartz integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula#:%7E:text=In%20complex%20analysis%2C%20a%20branch,values%20of%20its%20real%20part.) says $$f(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(\xi)\frac{\xi+z}{\xi-z}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}+iK$$ if $z\in D$, where $\xi=e^{i\theta}$ and $K\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

We differentiate this with respect to $z$,

$$f'(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(\xi)\frac{2\xi}{(\xi-z)^2}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.$$

Take $z=0$, we have $$f'(0)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(\xi)\frac{2}{\xi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.$$

Hence $$u_x(0)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(e^{i\theta})\cos\theta\,\frac{d\theta}{\pi}.$$ Since $u(e^{i\theta})\in[0,1]$, the maximum of this integral is $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

If instead $u$ is a harmonic function from $D$ to $[0,1]$, then what we have shown implies that for any $r\in(0,1),$ we have $ru_x(0)\leq\frac{2}{\pi}$, therefore, $u_x(0)\leq\frac{2}{\pi}$. This maximum can be attained: simply stipulate that $u(e^{i\theta})=1$ if $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $u(e^{i\theta})=0$ if $\theta\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$, then use the Poisson's formula with this boundary condition to find such $u$. Therefore, the maximum is $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

My question: is my solution correct and is there some way to do this without complex analysis? For example if we would like to generalize to $n$-dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: I did not try it, but I could imagine that you can obtain the corresponding result in $n$ dimensions by using the [$n$-dimensional Poisson formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball).

Comment: Thanks! I did try it before but the computation gets kind of complicated so I abandoned this approach. I'll do it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same answer you did, but I used the Poisson integral for the disc. Assuming, as you did at first, that $u$ is harmonic in $D(0,r)$ for some $r>1,$ we have, for $z\in D(0,1),$

$$u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi u(e^{it})(1-|z|^2)(|e^{it}-z|^2)^{-1}\, dt.$$

If $z=x\in (-1,1),$ this becomes

$$u(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi u(e^{it})(1-x^2)(|e^{it}-x|^2)^{-1}\, dt.$$

Now differentiate with respect to $x$ through the integral sign with respect to $x$ and set $x=0.$ We get

$$u_x(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi u(e^{it})2\cos t\, dt.$$

This is what you had, and thus $2/\pi$ is the desired maximum value of $u_x(0).$

We can do the same in higher dimensions. The Poisson kernel for the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is

$$P(x,\zeta) = (1-|x|^2)(|\zeta - x|^2)^{-n/2}.$$

Here $\zeta \in S,$ the unit sphere, and $x\in B,$ the unit ball, with $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n).$ Thus if we are interested in $u_{x_1}(0),$ we let $x=(x_1,0,\dots, 0)$ in the above to get

$$(1-x_1^2)(|\zeta -(x_1,0,\dots, 0) |^2)^{-n/2}.$$

Differentiate that with respect to $x_1,$ then set $x=(0,\dots,0).$ We get

$$u_{x_1}(0) = \frac{1}{\sigma(S)}\int_S u(\zeta)n\zeta_1\,d\sigma(\zeta).$$

($\sigma$ is surface area measure on $S.$) As in the case $n=2,$ the maximum value will occur with $u(\zeta) = \chi_{S+},$ where $S+=\{\zeta \in S: \zeta_1>0\}.$ That maximal value is, I think,

$$\tag 1\frac{V_{n-1}(B_{n-1})}{V_n(B_n)},$$

where $V_k$ is Lebesgue volume measure on $\mathbb R^k$ and $B_k$ is the corresponding unit ball. Note that $(1)$ checks out with our work in the $n=2$ case.

Check out the book Harmonic Function Theory, p. 123, where the authors discuss the Schwarz Lemma for harmonic functions: http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf